# I do not know how to turn a wheel on a given field

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I do not know how to do or what to override, so that after calling the function with the argument, the wheel rotated to the field with the number

I tried to do it using the radian method. CODE: https://codepen.io/xLUKIN/pen/dxGvRz

```
function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t /= d) * t;
    var tc = ts * t;
    return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
}
```

I would like that after calling the function with a numerical argument, the wheel would rotate on the given field with that number